# Preventing interaction between Tkinter LabelFrames

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am having an issue where the creation of one tkinter label frame is affecting a separate one. Below is some code that will recreate the issue. I would like the second label frame `self.group2` to extend lower than the bottom of the first frame `self.group1`. As the code stands, however, the bottom of `self.group1` is extended to match the end of `self.group2`.

```
import Tkinter

class gui(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        for x in xrange(0, 11):
            self.grid_rowconfigure(x,weight=1)
            self.grid_columnconfigure(x,weight=1)

        self.group1 = Tkinter.LabelFrame(self, text="Group1", padx=5, pady=5)
        self.group1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='NSEW')

        self.b1 = Tkinter.Button(self.group1, text='Click', command=self.b1_f)
        self.b1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='NSEW')

    def b1_f(self):
        self.group2 = Tkinter.LabelFrame(self, text="Group2", padx=5, pady=5)
        self.group2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='NSEW')

        for row_count in xrange(6):
            Tkinter.Label(self.group2, text=row_count).grid(row=row_count, column=1, sticky='NSEW')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # loop the window
    app = gui(None)
    app.mainloop()
```

Adding `rowspan=7` during the creation of group2 helps, but group1 is still modified.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The confusing bit that I found when working with layout managers is that they work on multiple 'layers'. In this example you have the window layer which have 2 LabelFrames, and then you have one layer for each LabelFrame. The layer are not connected to each other.

In this case the problem is in the 'window layer'. In this layer you have 2 LabelFrames that are placed on row 0 and uses sticky to fill out the entire area. This means that if one of the frames changes in size the other one also will change.

Try this:

```
import Tkinter

class gui(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

        self.group1 = Tkinter.LabelFrame(self, text="Group1", padx=5, pady=5)
        self.group1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='NSEW')

        self.b1 = Tkinter.Button(self.group1, text='Click', command=self.b1_f)
        self.b1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='NSEW')

    def b1_f(self):
        self.group2 = Tkinter.LabelFrame(self, text="Group2", padx=5, pady=5)
        self.group2.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='NSEW')

        for row_count in xrange(6):
            Tkinter.Label(self.group2, text=row_count).grid(row=row_count, column=1, sticky='NSEW')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # loop the window
    app = gui(None)
    app.mainloop()
```

Here I changed so the group2 frame rowspan is 2 and then set the weight=1 on just the second row. By doing so the first row shouldn't change in size even if the second row does.